# CharacterTable for symmetric groups $S_n$ with large $n$

Tags: packages, group-theory

I am looking for a package to generate character tables for symmetric groups $S_n$. At this moment I am using

```
FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", n}, "CharacterTable"]
```

but it works only for $n\leq 10$. Does there exist a package which can be used to get similar results for larger values of $n$?

Comment: For reference, [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/index.html) can do large groups, for example `Display(CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(30)));`

Comment: How to export these GAP's results into a file which are be imported then in Mathematica? I tried to type in GAP:  PrintTo("file1",Display(CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(4)))); but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Ok, I asked this question separetely here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360500/how-to-export-results-obtained-by-display-in-gap-to-a-txt-file  Nevertheless, I still would like to see if there a direct method to compute this in Mathematica, so I leave this question open.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a comment: we can use [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) to compute large character tables and then import them to Mathematica.

A simple GAP function based on [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/740177/632893):

```
storeSymmetricCharacterTable := function(n, filename)
    local c, f;
    c := CharacterTable("Symmetric", n);
    f := OutputTextFile(filename, false);
    SetPrintFormattingStatus(f, false);
    PrintTo(f, "SymmetricCharacterTable[", n, "] =\n");
    PrintTo(f, "  {\"CharacterParameters\"->");
    PrintTo(f, "{", JoinStringsWithSeparator(List(CharacterParameters(c), x->Concatenation("{",JoinStringsWithSeparator(x[2]),"}"))), "},\n");
    PrintTo(f, "   \"CharacterTable\"->");
    PrintTo(f, "{", JoinStringsWithSeparator(List(Irr(c), x->Concatenation("{",JoinStringsWithSeparator(x),"}"))), "}}\n");
    CloseStream(f);
end;;
```

Store this function in a file `ssct.gap`, then start GAP and run

```
Read("ssct.gap");
storeSymmetricCharacterTable(3, "symm_3.txt");
```

which now contains Mathematica-format data:

```
SymmetricCharacterTable[3] =
  {"CharacterParameters"->{{1,1,1},{2,1},{3}},
   "CharacterTable"->{{1,-1,1},{2,0,-1},{1,1,1}}}
```

Compare to Mathematica code:

```
FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 3}, "ConjugacyClassNames"]
(*    {"{1,1,1}", "{2,1}", "{3}"}    *)

FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 3}, "CharacterTable"]
(*    {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, -1}, {1, -1, 1}}    *)
```

Notice that the signs in the character tables differ between Mathematica and GAP.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find the source of the difference in signs and couldn't find a good reference for that. Any idea where I can find some information about this? Actually, the ones from Mathematica agree with Jackson's tables published in 1988.

Comment: Maybe a phase convention? You'd have to ask a real mathematician about the signs. Maybe ask on the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com)?